# ng-model with unique id inside ng-repeat ionic 1 angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create like button with ionic 1/angular js.

The problem is when like buttons doesnt work with ng-model within ng-repeat because all ng-model have same names.

This is the html so far.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
 <div class = "item item-text-wrap">
          <button class="button button-block icon ion-thumbsup" ng-model="islike" ng-class="islike== true?'button-on':'button-light'" ng-click="changeLikeState(item.id);"> Like</button>
       </div>
</div>
```

I want to initialize the button state if a user already like this item or not. If user already like the item, `islike` is set to true otherwise `islike` set to false.

I want to create a function to check like state with `$http.get` call and set the `islike` based on the results
The problem is there are multiple item with same islike, How do you set `item.id` within `ng-model="islike"` to identify specific button?

Is this the correct approach ? How to solve this in ionic/angularjs?

Comment: Based on this description, ideally, `islike` should be a property of each `item` object, e.g. `ng-model="item.islike"`

Comment: Can you show the sample angularjs code to initialize the button state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an `ng-model` for buttons. Simply pass the object into your function with `ng-click` to trigger any changes there. Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {"islike":false,"id":1},
    {"islike":false,"id":2},
    {"islike":false,"id":3},
  ];
  $scope.changeLikeState = function(item) {
    item.islike = !item.islike;
    console.log(item.id);
  }
});
```

```css
.button-on {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button-light {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button ng-class="{'button-on':item.islike,'button-light':!item.islike}" ng-click="changeLikeState(item);">
      Like
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $scope.items = [
    {"islike":false,"id":1},
    {"islike":false,"id":2},
    {"islike":false,"id":3},
  ] ---- this line deletes the original data in $scope.items (other data from $http get results)

Comment: @TomKur this just an example, don't use it literally, you can remove my `$scope.items` array and use yours. I don't know what your code looks like, so I wrote a static array that I can use for demonstration. Also CSS and wrapping HTML elements will be different. My point is to extend `$scope.items` with `islike` property (can be done in a for loop), then displaying it will be easy

Answer (score 0):

as pointed above in the comment `islike` should be a property of each item in your object, for example :-

let's assume your collection looks something like

```
 $scope.items = [{ name: 'pan cakes', islike: false }, 
              { name: 'pea nut butter', islike: true },
              { name: 'pizza', islike: true }]
```

along with other properties if there's an `id` associated too, that's more than enough otherwise you can always use the `$index` in `ng-repeat` to track the current `item in items`

your code then may look something like this:-

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by ($index)">
     <div class = "item item-text-wrap">
          <button class="button button-block icon ion-thumbsup" ng-model="item.islike" ng-class="item.islike == true?'button-on':'button-light'" ng-click="changeLikeState($index);"> Like</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

notice the change `track by` and instead of `islike` its not `item.islike`